# Can't get users location

Tags: android, permissions, gps, location, userlocation

So I've tried to get the users location and wanted it to popup as a `Toast()` or in the Logs but nothing happens.

I've added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` to the manifest and this is my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the users location
    locationManager = (LocationManager) 
this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Log.i("LOCATION", location.toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, location.toString(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle 
extras) {

            Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(status));
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    // Ask users permission to get location
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
    } else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The app asks for permission the first time and after I accept it doesn't show any signs of getting a location from the `OnStatusChanges()` method. I've tried to get `lastKnownLocation()`and it works but that's all...

Any idea what's missing?

Thanks!

Comment: are you testing your device indoors? or are you using emulator? GPS_PROVIDER doesn't likely work well indoors because it uses satellite to get your coordinates.

Comment: well, I'm still running some tests but I think you got it @L2_Paver ! It doesn't like to work indoors....
Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: I recommend you use NETWORK_PROVIDER to, NETWORK PROVIDER work even indoors but require network services(data consumption). you switch between  GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER  so it will work all the time.

Comment: I also recommend you use this `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER); `to get the last coordinates. PASSIVE_PROVIDER get the last coordinates capture by GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER.

Comment: Thank you so much!!